# Why can't I find Java after installing it?

Tags: windows, java

I downloaded [Java from their site](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp) and installed it

but now I cannot find it on my computer!

Where can I find it? Im running 'Windows

Comment: Is this a troll job?

Comment: What's your Operating System?

Comment: What do you need it for? Browser? Stand alone java programs? Programming?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look under `c:\Program Files\Java` and `c:\Program Files (x86)\Java`.

Answer (score 1):

Default installation is usually C:\Program Files\Java[jdk|jre]_[version]\

Answer (score 0):

Search for the file `java.exe` in your computer.